# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ca' of null when dragging Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, angular, ionic2, zonejs

I have an Ionic 2 beta 7 app (also happens in Beta 6) that uses the Google Maps JavaScript API.

If I click down on the map, drag it and "throw" the map before releasing the click, it causes this error to occur on the next attempt at dragging the map.

Here is the JavaScript stack trace

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ca' of null
>       at *.r.Kj (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/7/common.js:215:70)
>       at Object.*.B.trigger (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY:93:119)
>       at dy (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/7/common.js:164:140)
>       at . (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/7/common.js:163:441)
>       at Object._.B.trigger (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY:93:119)
>       at *.r.dl (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/7/common.js:228:350)
>       at Kv.*.r.fm (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/7/common.js:195:106)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:356:38)
>       at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:256:48)
>       at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:423:34)

Although it doesn't seem to cause any UI issues from a users point of view it would be good to know if there is a way to prevent this from happening?

**Note**

Dragging the map and releasing it when the mouse is static this error doesn't occur on the next drag.

**Plunker Example**

I've created a [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vmlXrcfHdGwC0a79anUw?p=preview) which replicates the problem. Follow these steps:

1. Open `Developer Tools` (F12)
2. Drag and throw map
3. Try and drag map again
4. Error is thrown and written to the console

**Update**

Question stack trace and title have been updated to match what is caught in Ionic 2 beta 10

**Track on GitHub**

This issue has been raised on the ZoneJS GitHub page so you can track it [here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/359)

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. did you figure out the issue or find a workaround?

Comment: Not figured it out yet, im unsure if its related to Google's API or just zone.js failing to do something during asynchronous calls. It doesn't really affect the end user so i'm not spending too much time worrying about it yet. Hopefully somebody will come along and provide a fix or maybe it will require an update to Angular2 or the Google API

Comment: thanks - I'm in the same place. parking it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to notify anyone who hasn't followed the issue on GitHub (the one I linked in this question) this error has now been fixed in version v0.16.7 of ZoneJS